# Hibernate failed to load spatial data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spatial

I am using MySql, Hibernate 4 and [hibernate-spatial-4.0-M1](http://www.hibernatespatial.org). I tried simply save and load entity, saving was successfull but loading throws exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
        at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(MySQLGeometryValueExtractor.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.extract(AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.extract(AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2704)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1541)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1473)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1373)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2438)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2424)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2254)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at com.mm.dao.hibernate.GeoDAO.getById(GeoDAO.java:33)
        at com.mm.service.GeoService.getById(GeoService.java:24)
        at com.mm.service.GeoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$aeb6c7aa.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
        at com.mm.service.GeoLocationService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f879610f.getById(<generated>)
        at com.mm.controllers.GeoController.updateGeodata(GeoController.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHa
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingH
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandle
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My entity:

```
public class GeoEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Point geom;
        //...
}
```

entity hbm.xml

```
<property name="geom" type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType">
        <column name="geom" sql-type="Geometry" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```

hibernate config:

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect</prop>
```

load:

```
(GeoEntity)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from GeoEntity where id=:id")
                .setInteger("id", id)
                .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with old jdbc driver